# Complex join with multiple one to many relationships

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to pull some orders with their associated items and notes.

Each order can have one or many items and none or many notes.

Here's some example data;

Orders:

| OrderNumber |
| --- |
| 1 |
| 2 |
| 3 |

Items:

| OrderNumber | Description |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Laptop |
| 1 | TV |
| 2 | Projector |
| 3 | Laptop |
| 3 | Projector |

Notes:

| OrderNumber | Note |
| --- | --- |
| 2 | Wheelchair access is required |
| 2 | Client will be on site 2 hrs before doors open |
| 3 | Tea and coffee is to be served at 10am |

Here's what I expect the output to look like:

| OrderNumber | Item | Note |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Laptop | NULL |
| 1 | TV | NULL |
| 2 | Projector | Wheelchair access is required |
| 2 | NULL | Client will be on site 2 hrs before doors open |
| 3 | Laptop | Tea and coffee is to be served at 10am |
| 3 | Projector | NULL |

I've tried a bunch of approaches using cross apply, and rank but have been unable to achieve my desired results.

Here's an example of one of the techniques which works but is a mess and will only work for a max of 5 items or notes. I think introducing a CTE might be the answer?

```
SELECT
    , ER101_ORD_NBR
    , ER101_DESC
    , RANK () OVER (PARTITION BY ER101_ORG_CODE, ER101_EVT_ID, ER101_ORD_NBR ORDER BY ER101_DESC)
        Order_Desc_Rank
INTO
    #order_items
FROM
    ER101_ACCT_ORDER_DTL

SELECT
    , CC025_ORDER
    , CC025_NOTE_TEXT
    , RANK () OVER (ORDER BY CC025_NOTE_TEXT)
        Note_Rank
INTO
    #notes
FROM
    CC025_NOTES_EXT
    
DECLARE @i_items INT, @i_notes INT
SELECT @i_items = MAX(Order_Desc_Rank) FROM #order_items
SELECT @i_notes = MAX(Note_Rank) FROM #notes

SELECT
    ER100_ORD_NBR
    , ER101_DESC
    , CC025_NOTE_TEXT
FROM
    ER100_ACCT_ORDER
CROSS APPLY
(
    SELECT 1 _RANK
    UNION ALL SELECT 2 WHERE @i_items >= 2 OR @i_notes >= 2
    UNION ALL SELECT 3 WHERE @i_items >= 3 OR @i_notes >= 3
    UNION ALL SELECT 4 WHERE @i_items >= 4 OR @i_notes >= 4
    UNION ALL SELECT 5 WHERE @i_items >= 5 OR @i_notes >= 5
) ZZZ
OUTER APPLY
(
    SELECT
        *
    FROM
        #order_items
    WHERE
        ER100_ORD_NBR = ER101_ORD_NBR   
        AND ZZZ._RANK = Order_Desc_Rank
) ER101
OUTER APPLY
(
    SELECT
        *
    FROM
        #notes
    WHERE
        CC025_ORDER = ER100_ORD_NBR
        AND Note_Rank = ZZZ._RANK
) CC025
```

Comment: Thanks @DaleK i've added the best effort so far. I think i'm hugely overcomplicating it though.

Comment: why 2 Null  client will be on site...   and not 2 Projector client will be on site... ?

Comment: Unclear why `Projector` is joined with `Wheelchair access is required` and not `Client will be on site 2 hrs before doors open` or why it's not joined with both

Comment: Sorry @DaleK something went wrong- I added it again :) Looks similar to Sean has - just trying to see if that solution would work...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't seem to have a column here you can use for ordering so I just decided to use Description and Note for the relevant tables. I had to leverage `ROW_NUMBER` to generate a value to use for ordering. You could skip this step if your real data has something you can use. Here is a full working example of how you can use a full outer join to accomplish this. Also notice how I created tables and sample data to work with. This is how you should post your questions in the future as it makes easy for others to help.

```
declare @Orders table 
(
    OrderNumber int
)
insert @Orders values (1), (2), (3)

declare @Items table 
(
    OrderNumber int
    , Description varchar(20)
)
insert @Items values
(1, 'Laptop')
, (1, 'TV')
, (2, 'Projector')
, (3, 'Laptop')
, (3, 'Projector')


declare @Notes table 
(
    OrderNumber int
    , Note varchar(100)
)
insert @Notes values
(2, 'Wheelchair access is required')
, (2, 'Client will be on site 2 hrs before doors open')
, (3, 'Tea and coffee is to be served at 10am')
;

with cteItems as
(
    select i.OrderNumber
        , i.Description
        , RowNum = ROW_NUMBER() over(partition by o.OrderNumber order by i.Description)
    from @Orders o
    join @Items i on i.OrderNumber = o.OrderNumber
)
, cteNotes as
(
    select n.OrderNumber
        , n.Note
        , RowNum = ROW_NUMBER() over(partition by o.OrderNumber order by n.Note)
    from @Orders o
    join @Notes n on n.OrderNumber = o.OrderNumber
)
select OrderNumber = coalesce(i.OrderNumber, n.OrderNumber)
    , i.Description
    , n.Note
from cteItems i
full outer join cteNotes n on i.OrderNumber = n.OrderNumber and i.RowNum = n.RowNum
 order by coalesce(i.OrderNumber, n.OrderNumber)
```

Comment: Awesome, that's what I was missing. I need to INNER JOIN the main table separately to each of the related tables, then a FULL OUTER JOIN.
I was sure a FULL OUTER JOIN was what I needed, just couldn't quite figure out how to achieve it. Thanks a mill

Answer (score 0):

To prevent the cartesian result in your output due to the possibility of multiple notes, you would need to pre-aggregate them into a single row per order.  If all you are looking for of the items is a comma list, then same applies.  Then, the rest should be a simple join.

```
select
      o.orderNumber,
      i.NumberItems,
      i.AllItems, 
      coalesce( n.NumberNotes, 0 ) NumberNotes,
      coalesce( n.AllNotes, '' ) AllNotes
   from
      orders o

         JOIN
         ( select
                 orderNumber,
                 count(*) NumberItems,
                 string_agg( description, ', ') AllItems
              from
                 items
              group by 
                 orderNumber ) i
           on o.orderNumber = i.orderNumber

         LEFT JOIN
         ( select
                 orderNumber,
                 count(*) NumberNotes,
                 string_agg( note, ', ') AllNotes
              from
                 notes
              group by 
                 orderNumber ) n
            on o.orderNumber = n.orderNumber
```

I did a LEFT-JOIN to the pre-aggregate of notes since they are not required, but normal join for items since that is the basis of any actual order.

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried this?

```
SELECT o.OrderNumber
, i.Description AS Item
, n.Note
FROM Orders o 
    INNER JOIN Items i ON 
        i.OrderNumber = o.OrderNumber
    LEFT JOIN Notes n ON 
        n.OrderNumber = o.OrderNumber
```

Comment: That will return duplicates. So if I have an order with 2 items and 2 notes it will return 4 rows etc

Comment: I think that the root issue here is that the Notes and Items tables lacks a column that can relate back to each other (such as a "OrderItemDetailNumber").  Otherwise, you'll constantly spin your wheels with this issue.